Edit a surface generated with TTF_RenderText?
I'm trying to make a menu using the SDL2. I have several items consisting of a few indicative words, that I make into surfaces using TTF_RenderText_Blended, then make them into textures through SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface, then display them all in a column, one below another. This works fine, but for the sake of interactivity, I want to make the keyboard shortcut for each item explicit through underlining the corresponding character in each item.
This is my code:
int char_w,char_h; TTF_SizeText(font, "C", &char_w,&char_h);
...
s_item =TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, ">  New game", RED);
SDL_Rect r =(SDL_Rect){char_w*3,char_h-5,char_w,3};
SDL_FillRect(s_item, &r, 79);
items[n]->t =SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, s_item);

I figured the simpliest way to achieve the effect I wanted was to draw on my surface a slim rectangle under the character I'm interested in, before making it into a texture.
However, this does not work, the text shows on screen but no underline.
I tried a variety of other methods, uselessly more complicated imo, such as creating the texture, setting the render target to that texture and drawing a line, or blitting two surfaces together, to no avail.
Possibly related, but I don't understand the suggested solution.

TTF_RenderText_Blended returns a new 32-bit ARGB surface. When calling SDL_FillRect, if the color value contains an alpha component then the destination is simply filled with that alpha information, no blending takes place.
My assumption is that since you are passing 79 as the color, which in ARGB format is just dark blue, the alpha component is not taken into account and the destination keeps its transparency.
Try using 0x4F000000 as the color instead.
